# How to disable Personal View in Sharepoint 2010 Foundation

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I have a public sharepoint site (Sharepoint 2010 Foundation). Site looks great in public side but when i log in as a admin in that site look and feel of whole site changes. But when i add ?pageview=shared as query string url it switches back to public view again and looks fine. Is there a way to address this problem, can we disable personal view so that site is consistant everywhere.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

When logged in as admin, in the drop down menu next to the name select "Reset Page Content"

Comment: I have lots of custom contents in my page, isnt that option is going to reset to factory mode?

Comment: No it's only resetting from personal view to the shared view, such that you see what everybody else sees.